# app time is 1 hour ahead in spite of correct time zone

Tags: javascript, node.js

Used `process.env.TZ = "Asia/Tehran";` at the very beginning of server.js.

At `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "env TZ='Asia/Tehran' node server.js",
},
```

The issue is my Nodejs server is 1 hour ahead!

It's **11:10 AM** right now but it shows **12:10 PM** using code below:

```
const now = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: "2-digit" });
console.log(':: ', now);
```

**Note:
I'm using `node-schedule` to schedule some jobs and now all of them have changed.**

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

// Run at 00:00 AM each day
schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 * * *', () => {
  // code here to run
});
```

How can fix this?

Comment: 1 hour changes always make me think "Summer/Winter" time, so is that a kind of thing Iran does? Could it be that?

Comment: Maybe but if this is the issue how can I solve it in nodejs? I'm using `schedule` to schedule some jobs. I need to fix this

Comment: A quick google shows that Tehran does not use DST - but *did* just last year.  Maybe the js engine for locale hasn't been updated?

Comment: Pedantic: 12:10 AM is 11 hours *before* 11:10 AM  - perhaps you meant 12:10 PM?   Tehran (from google again) is UTC+3:30, so it's not that it's converting to UTC.

Comment: So guys there is no fix for this??

Comment: [Version 2022b](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2022-August/000071.html) of the [IANA Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) included a change to Asia/Tehran to stop using DST. You're likely using an older version of the data and need to upgrade. There will probably be a time zone data package available for your operating system.

Comment: I'm using a shred host as server, what should I do now?